# Access MS Analysis Services Cube via Excel on Mac?

Tags: excel, macos, ssas, excel-2008

In MS Excel 2007 on PC you can connect to a MS Analysis Services Cube via Excel. I can't see how to do the same on Mac using Excel 2008 there.

Does anyone know how to access the OLAP cube data on Mac?

Answer (score 2):

OLAP isn't supported on Mac Excel, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I still see negative answers for SSAS OLAP Cube with Excel 2011 Mac version. [See Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/ssas-pivot-not-working-on-office-2011/de6f40dc-27e6-442d-bf6b-bb7e3cd6f79d?tab=AllReplies#tabs)
Looks not supported yet.

Cilvic : can you suggest us how you were able to connect from Mac Excel 2011?

Comment: Unfortunately I changed companies and don't have access anymore. What we usually did is just create the files on a PC and then open them on a Mac. Which worked quite ok with Office 2011.